# Regex - how to match body part in xml

Tags: xml, colors, richtextbox

I am trying to highlighting the the body part and tags part of Xml in different colors in rithtextbox.

```
Regex regExp = new Regex("<[^>]+>");
foreach (Match match in regExp.Matches(richTextBox3.Text))
{
      richTextBox3.Select(match.Index, match.Length);
      richTextBox3.SelectionColor = Color.blue;
} 

regExp = new Regex("(?!<[^>]+>)");
foreach (Match match in regExp.Matches(richTextBox3.Text))
{
      richTextBox3.Select(match.Index, match.Length);
      richTextBox3.SelectionColor = Color.Green;
}
```

problem is its not matches the body part(other than tags)

Comment: try the regex like `"^<body.*>$"` for matching body part. I'm not sure it'll work or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer here is the solution

```
Regex regExp = new Regex("<[^>]+>");
MatchCollection a = regExp.Matches(richTextBox3.Text);
for(int i=0;i<a.Count;i++)
{
     richTextBox3.Select(a[i].Index, a[i].Length);
     richTextBox3.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
     if (i < a.Count - 1)
     {
         if (a[i+1].Index-(a[i].Index + a[i].Length + 1) > 0)
         {
              richTextBox3.Select(a[i].Index + a[i].Length , a[i + 1].Index - (a[i].Index + a[i].Length));

              richTextBox3.SelectionColor = Color.Green;

         }
     }
}
```